# Javascript - How to find two elements with more value?

Tags: javascript, arrays, frontend

I have an array and I'm trying to get two of the highest values of the array, for example:

```
[1, 2, 3, 4, 3, 1, 0]
```

I need the return to be like this: `[ 4, 3]`

How can this be done? At the moment I have a function that returns me the max of the array only, (in this example, only [4]). But I need the highest and the second, if it repeats, like this example (3 appears two times), only one of them, to make an array of two elements.

My function at the moment:

```
    indexOfMax(arr) {  
    var max = -Infinity;
    var maxIndices = [];
    for (var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
        if (arr[i] === max) {
          maxIndices.push(i);
        } else if (arr[i] > max) {
            maxIndices = [i];
            max = arr[i];
        }
    }
    return maxIndices;

 },
```

Thanks for all the answers! You guys rock!

Comment: Use sort and then slice?

Comment: Do you need the elements or the *indeces* of the elements?

Answer (score 0):

You can do this using the `sort` function and get the two first values of the results

```js
const sortedArray = [1, 2, 3, 4].sort((a, b) => {
  if(a < b) return 1

  return -1
})

sortedArray[0] // 4
sortedArray[1] // 3

// or

const [highest, secondHighest] = sortedArray
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following code

```
function largestTwo(arr){
    return arr.sort().slice(-2).reverse();
}
```

Here's how it works.

1. `arr.sort()` sorts the array in **ascending order**
2. `.slice(-2)` slices out the last two elements

   They are the largest two, with **largest one at last**
3. Then we use `reverse()` to get our desired result as array with **largest one in front**

Answer (score 0):

You could take a [`Set`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Set) for getting unique values, sort ascending and take the two last elements of the array.

```js
const
    array = [1, 2, 3, 4, 3, 1, 0],
    highest = [...new Set(array)]
        .sort((a, b) => a - b)
        .slice(-2);

console.log(highest);
```

Answer (score 0):

You could first sort the array. Then use a set to get unique values only if necessary and finally slice the last two elements of the array.

```
let arr = [1, 2, 3, 4, 3, 1, 0];

arr.sort((a, b) => a-b);

arr = [...new Set(arr)]; //if you only want unique values

let result = arr.slice((arr.length - 2), arr.length);

console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 0):

this was actually one of my favourite question during interview. To be more specific - to find the second biggest number in array.

Sorting is valid solution for small arrays (or in service that does not do this operation often or you do not care about CPU performance at all), however I was telling them that array can be huge - and therefore the sort operation (which runs in `O(n log n)`) is too expensive and I want to do it in linear time.

This is the most straightforward approach - just remember highest number and second highest number as you iterate through it:

```js
let _arr = [1, 2, 3, 4, 3, 1, 0];

function findTwoBiggestNumbers(arr) {
  let biggest = -1;
  let secondBiggest = -1;
  for (let i=0; i < arr.length; i++){
    if (arr[i] > secondBiggest) {
      secondBiggest = arr[i];
      if (secondBiggest > biggest) {
        const temp = biggest;
        biggest = secondBiggest;
        secondBiggest = temp;
      }   
    } 
  }
  
  return [biggest, secondBiggest]
}

console.log(findTwoBiggestNumbers(_arr));

To get indexes, just remember them as well.
```

```js
    let _arr = [1, 2, 3, 4, 3, 1, 0];

    function findTwoBiggestNumbersIndexes(arr) {
      let biggest = -1;
      let biggestIndex;
      let secondBiggest = -1;
      let secondBiggestIndex;
      for (let i=0; i < arr.length; i++){
        if (arr[i] > secondBiggest) {
          secondBiggest = arr[i];
          secondBiggestIndex = i;
          if (secondBiggest > biggest) {
            const temp = biggest;
            const tempIndex = biggestIndex;
            biggest = secondBiggest;
            biggestIndex = secondBiggestIndex;
            secondBiggest = temp;
            secondBiggestIndex = tempIndex;
          }   
        } 
      }
      
      return [biggestIndex, secondBiggestIndex]
    }

    console.log(findTwoBiggestNumbersIndexes(_arr));
```

Note that when you have indexes, you dont need to remember exact numbers, because you can always get their values from index (i.e. `arr[biggestIndex]`) - however it requires some extra work in initialization of these indexes.

---

Note - there can be also code-minimalistic approach that is easy to understand, easy to write and it is still Linear time. And thats the thing you go through the array two times - first you get max, and second time you get secondMax (basically same max but without the max you already found)

```js
let _arr = [1, 2, 3, 4, 3, 1, 0];

function findBiggestReduce(arr) {
  const max = arr.reduce( (biggest, current) => biggest < current? current : biggest);
  const secondMax = arr.reduce( (biggest, current) => current !== max && biggest < current? current : biggest);
  return [max, secondMax];
}

console.log(findBiggestReduce(_arr));
```

Also the indexes are easy to track with this approach

```js
    let _arr = [1, 2, 3, 4, 3, 1, 0];

    function findBiggestReduce(arr) {
      const maxIndex = arr.reduce( (biggestIndex, current, index) => arr[biggestIndex] < current? index : biggestIndex);
      const secondMaxIndex = arr.reduce( (biggestIndex, current, index) => index !== maxIndex && arr[biggestIndex] < current? index : biggestIndex);
      return [maxIndex, secondMaxIndex];
    }

    console.log(findBiggestReduce(_arr));
```

Comment: That's it. Thanks a lot! But in case i want the index of the element, how could I return the biggest and secondBiggest indexes? I'm new to Javascript, sorry

Comment: @nejelo3022 - added index solution

Comment: Thanks man! You rock! One day I'll be the one helping newbies hahah!